# Bootstrap spoiling the ul and li elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a simple web app. Today, I decided to include bootstrap, to use some UI elemets. Anyhow, including bootstrap is spoiling whatever css I had developed myself. Even `!important` is unable to solve the problem.

Before Bootstrap css file inclusion:

[image: Before including CSS file of Bootstrap]

After:

[image: After including CSS file of Bootstrap]

What's wrong? What should I do?

EDIT:

After, including the list-group and list-group-item class, I am getting:

[image]

So, finally, how do I have the text come in the same line as the checkboxes?

Comment: Pls show your related `HTML` and `CSS` for better solution.

Comment: bootstrap css is over-riding your css...you can use `inspect-tool` to verify it and then assign classes in more proper manner to avoid over-riding! :)

Comment: @coder Show your code or make a http://fiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inco-operate your css into the class names adopted by bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you should use `list` in bootstrap :-

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUVkZ/)

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Hi</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> How</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Are</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
</ul>
```

You need to apply bootstrap classes for implementing your new layout with bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group

Answer (score 2):

This syntax will ensure your checkbox labels are also clickable:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Check me!</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Check me too!</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```